# Elementary Series question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Are these series convergent or divergent?

$$ \sum_{}^\infty [\sin(\frac{n\pi}{6})]^n  $$

and

$$\sum_{}^\infty [\sin(\frac{n\pi}{7})]^n $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values of the sine cycle through a finite number of values. You can easily see that $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left|\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{6}\right)\right| = 1$$
while
$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left|\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{7}\right)\right| < 1$$
This means the first sum cannot converge while the second sum will be absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Taking $\,n=3k\,\,,\,k\in\Bbb N\,\,,\,\,k\,\,\text{odd}$ , we get

$$\sin\frac{n\pi}{6}=\sin\frac{k\pi}{2}=\pm 1\Longrightarrow \sin^n\frac{n\pi}{2}\rlap{\;\;\;\;\;/}\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{}0$$

so the series cannot converge.